# How can I determine the generic type argument for an interface used by a derived class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Consider a vast set of properties that all implement various interfaces, among them being `ICustomProperty<T>`.

I need to find all distinct type arguments used for `T`.

Example:

```
AgeProp : ICustomProperty<double>
SizeProp : ICustomProperty<string>
NameProp : ICustomProperty<string>
GradeProp : ICustomProperty<int>
DetailProp:  ICustomProperty<IDetailValue>
```

As I result I would like a list containing the types for `double`, `string`, `int`, `IDetailValue`.

I've figured out this way, but I'm hoping there is a better way:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetDistinctGenericTypeArguments<TBase>(IEnumerable<Type> inputTypes)
    {
        foreach (var t in inputTypes)
        {
            var baseType = t.GetInterfaces()
                .FirstOrDefault(i => 
                    i.IsGenericType 
                        && 
                    (i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICustomProperty<>))
                );

            if (baseType == null) continue;

            yield return baseType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        }
    }

    //Usage:
    var valueTypes = GetDistinctGenericTypeArguments(inputTypes).Distinct().ToList();
```

Specifically, I was wondering, if there is a better way than calling `GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(...)`.

Is there?

Also, in the code above `typeof(ICustomProperty<>)` is hard-coded, because I cannot implement `GetDistinctGenericTypeArguments<T>(...)` and call `GetDistinctGenericTypeArguments<ICustomProperty<>>(...)`, because the compiler then complains: *Unexpected use of an unbound generic name*.

Is there a way around that as well?

Comment: Why are you concerned about that call?

Comment: @Eric J. aesthetics, curiosity, performance

Comment: Aesthetics are subjective. Curiousity is always good. Performance... does it matter in your case? (Worrying too much about microoptimizations tends to get in the way of shipping features).

Comment: @Eric J. True, performance is totally sufficient for me. Curiosity killed the cat's deadline ;o)

Comment: Cache the filtered `GetInterfaces` for a given type into a `Dictionary<Type, Type[]>`

Comment: @Charlieface: I was going to suggest the same *if* performance was an actual issue. But I'm against introducing complexity without a specific reason to do so.